# Highcharts with sql server data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, highcharts

I am just starting using highchart and I need to render values from an sql server database on it.

Please, what is the best approach for me to do this using asp.net as the server side language.

Thanks in advance
Thanks for the response guys, I am making a bit of a progress. However getting the xAxis categories dynamically from the database is proving difficult. Here is my code below

```
DataSet dsSeries = new DataSet();
       public string hidValues1;
       public string hidXCategories1;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)

            dsSeries=BindData();

            if (dsSeries == null) return;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dsSeries.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                hidXCategories1=hidXCategories1+ dr["symbol"].ToString()+",";

            }

            foreach (DataRow dr1 in dsSeries.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                hidValues1=hidValues1+dr1["value"].ToString()+",";

            }


        }

        public DataSet BindData()
        {
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Chartdata"].ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT symbol,value FROM Ticker";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                return ds;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/exporting.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var firstSeries = '<%=hidValues1 %>';
            var xAxis = '<%=hidXCategories1 %>';
            var banksname;
            var seriesOne = new Array();
            seriesOne = firstSeries.split(',');
            for (var i = 0; i < seriesOne.length; i++) {

                seriesOne[i] = parseInt(seriesOne[i]);
            }
            var xAxisSeries = new Array();
            xAxisSeries = xAxis.split(',');
            for (var i = 0; i < xAxisSeries.length; i++) {

                banksname =banksname+ seriesTwo[i];

            }


            var _MyArray = seriesOne;
            var _MyArray2 = banksname;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'line'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories:[_MyArray2]
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Fruit eaten'
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name:'Share Price',
                        data:_MyArray
                    }]


                });
                $('tspan').last().remove();
            });  
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

The yAxis data populates and renders properly on the chart, however the xAxis categories still displays in figures(which is a number listing of the categories in the database table.

Comment: This question may be to broad to get any useful answers, but from highcharts perspective - once the data is in a javascript array in the web page then all is well.

Answer (score 5):

[DotNet.Highcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) give you the possibility to easily build the Highcharts on the server site without any javascript code. Here is the code of how you can create you chart in your ASP.NET application:

```
Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Fruit Consumption" })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = _MyArray2 })
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Fruit eaten" } })
            .SetSeries(new Series { Name = "Share Price", Data = new Data(_MyArray) });
```

For more samples go here: http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/80650

Answer (score 1):

[Highcharts.Net](http://highcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/79560) is another alternative that you can consider for integrating Highcharts into your ASP .Net website. In fact, the exact problem being faced by you has been discussed (and solved) [here](http://highcharts.codeplex.com/discussions/286773)

Answer (score 0):

var firstSeries = '<%=hidValues1 %>';
            var xAxis = '<%=hidXCategories1 %>';
here hidValues1
and hidXCategories are column name of table?
"on debug its showing error in current context hidvalues1 not found..